# SQL: The query works, but goes a mistake?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The query works, but I get an error trying to see the error but it can not.
All variable get "value='1' " when marked....

```
$tuning = SESSION['tuning']));
$garanciq = (!empty($_SESSION['garanciq']));
$avtopilot = (!empty($_SESSION['avtopilot'])); 
$servo = (!empty($_SESSION['servo']));   
$tiptronik = (!empty($_SESSION['tiptronik']));
$servo = (!empty($_SESSION['servo']));
$service = (!empty($_SESSION['service']));
$bord = (!empty($_SESSION['bord']));
$navi = (!empty($_SESSION['navi']));
$volan = (!empty($_SESSION['volan']));  
$zastrahovka = (!empty($_SESSION['zastrahovka']));    

$iInsert= new general();
$iInsert->query("INSERT INTO  other_checkbox 
                 (tuning, garanciq, avtopilot, servo, tiptronik,
                  bord_komp, serviz_knijka, navig_sistema, desen_volan, 
                  zastrahovka) 
                 VALUES " . "(:tuning, :garanciq, avtopilot, :servo, 
                              :tiptronik, :bord, :serviceBook, :navi, 
                              :volan, :zastrahovka)");

$iInsert->bind(':tuning', $tuning);
$iInsert->bind(':garanciq', $garanciq);
$iInsert->bind(':avtopilot', $avtopilot);
$iInsert->bind(':servo', $servo);
$iInsert->bind(':tiptronik', $tiptronik);
$iInsert->bind(':bord', $bord);
$iInsert->bind(':serviceBook', $service);
$iInsert->bind(':navi', $navi);
$iInsert->bind(':volan', $volan);
$iInsert->bind(':zastrahovka', $zastrahovka);
$iInsert->execute();
$iInsert->debugDumpParams(); ->get error, but have Fatal Error !
$insert_other_chek = $iInsert->lastInsertId();->get LastInsertId
```

I get this error

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\ClassGeneral.php on line 45

Fatal error: Call to undefined method general::debugDumpParams() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\publicFinish.php on line 165
```

This is  my  class General !

```
class general {

    private $db;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new connect();
        $this->db = $this->db->connectDb();
    }
    public function query($sql) {
        $this->stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    }  
    public function execute() {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Where are the variables coming from?

Comment: `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables...` - You should really see to that error message by making sure you're calling `->bind();` on every placeholder in your query.

Comment: You also don't have a 'debugDumpParams()' or bind() method in the class you have posted.

Comment: If you format you code **in a readable way** Errors jump out at you a lot easier than coding in gobldegook!

Comment: The first error is that you missed the colon `:` from this parameter `avtopilot,` Again _format your code so you can actually read it_. **it helps**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
avtopilot
```

with

```
:avtopilot
```

in query

```
$iInsert->query("
    INSERT INTO  other_checkbox 
        (tuning, garanciq, avtopilot, servo, tiptronik, bord_komp, serviz_knijka, navig_sistema, desen_volan, zastrahovka) 
    VALUES
        (:tuning, :garanciq, :avtopilot, :servo, :tiptronik, :bord, :serviceBook, :navi, :volan, :zastrahovka)
");
```

Comment: Only in the `VALUES` list, not the column list.

Answer (score 1):

in your class general you don't have the functions `bind` and `debugDumpParams`

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an advise.
Do not use that class from culttt article.

It doesn't make any good compared to vanilla PDO, but has some serious drawbacks.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO  other_checkbox 
             (tuning, garanciq, avtopilot, servo, tiptronik,
              bord_komp, serviz_knijka, navig_sistema, desen_volan, 
              zastrahovka) 
             VALUES (:tuning, :garanciq, :avtopilot, :servo, 
                          :tiptronik, :bord, :serviceBook, :navi, 
                          :volan, :zastrahovka)");

$stmt->execute(array($tuning, $garanciq,$avtopilot,$servo,$tiptronik,
               $bord,$service,$navi,$volan, $zastrahovka));
$insert_other_chek = $stmt->lastInsertId();
```

is all the code you need.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have function bind() into the class general

Comment: He's not getting an error from the `bind` function, why do you think he doesn't have it?